# Intelijj IDEA: Autocompletion on spacebar does not work

Tags: actionscript-3, intellij-idea, autocomplete

IntelliJ IDEA (ActionScript, SDK: air + asc 2.0).

Need auto-completion on the <kbd>SPACE</kbd>:

```
myVa -> [SPACE] -> myVariable
```

Now when I press on the spacebar just insert a whitespace. Input `,` `.` `;` works as it should. The problem occurs in **.as** files. In **java**, **xml** files everything works fine.

Option is enabled (see screenshot).
[Intellij IDEA autocompletion settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TAN5a.png)
    enter code here

**UPDATED. Workaround:**

**Settings > Keymap > Editor Actions > Choose Lookup Item > add keyboard shortcut "Space"**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an open bug:

- [IDEA-80502](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-80502) Code completion: selecting an element with the Space (ActionScript)

Comment: Thanks! The bug was found 5 years ago :)